# add item to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add an item to a DropDownList from an Oracle datareader, but I keep getting an error that states the line has some invalid arguments.

Can I simply specify the text and the value? In which case, I want them to be the same value coming from the datareader.

```
TRef.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["t_ref"], dr["t_ref"]));
```

Comment: Is TRef an object of type [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx)? Are you getting the correct values from the Oracle datareader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListItem can take two strings as parameters, you are passing two objects.  Try converting the dr object to a string:

```
TRef.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["t_ref"].ToString(), dr["t_ref"].ToString()));
```

Alternatively to be cleaner:

```
 var t_ref = dr["t_ref"].ToString();
 TRef.Items.Add(new ListItem(t_ref, t_ref));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx

Comment: thanks, thought Id tried this, turned out I missed the () after the ToString - doh!

Answer (score 0):

`dr["t_ref"]` returns object.

```
TRef.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["t_ref"].ToString(), dr["t_ref"].ToString()));
```